# Newton like methods for Root finding modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have a polynomial $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ that is easy to compute for any $x$ but has an absurdly large degree $d > 2^{256}$. I know for a fact that it has a zero and I would like to find it.

I was wondering, consider a modified newtons method where instead of
$$ x \to x - f(x)/f'(x)$$
we take the forward difference map
$$x \to x - f(x)/\Delta f(x)$$
and study this modulo $q$. Has this been studied?
Under what conditions will I get my zero?

In general I'm looking for root finding methods in a finite field that don't take gcds (I can't because of the degree) and only rely on point evaluations.

Comment: I do not think that numerical methods work in a discrete ring like $\mathbb Z_q$

Comment: Usually they don't, but are there any similar methods that do?

Comment: Hensel's Lemma is essentially Newton's method recast for congruences, only it doesn't quite do what you want it to.

Comment: Can't you use $x^q-x$ to bring the degree $d$ down (i.e., replace $p(x)$ with $p(x)\pmod{x^q-x}$ to get degree $<q$), or is $q$ also large?

Comment: $q$ is a prime, and I can't take the degree down since $q$ is large.